# Powershell doesn't recognize openssl even after I added it to the system path

Tags: powershell, cmd, openssl

I am on a 64bit Windows 10. I installed `Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.0f` and added the install directory `C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin` to my system `PATH`.
Upon running it in cmd or Powershell, I get:

> openssl : The term 'openssl' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

What else am I missing?

Comment: In a cmd window, if you CD into c:\OpsnSSL-Win64\bin, do you see openssl.exe or openssl.bat or openssl.cmd in that directory?  If you do, does it run from that directory?  If it runs, your PATH may be malformed somehow.

Comment: @mao Ok, from the bin folder, I can run it, but only with ./openssl instead of openssl. In other directories I can't run it in any way.

Comment: This suggests your PATH is malformed. Check it carefully , check the separators (usually ;) and if directories have spaces they need to be quoted.

Comment: The directory I've put is C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\. Putting it in quotes like "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\" doesn't change anything. I also tried remove the last slash, still same thing. I guess I'll have to write the path and exe manually instead of "openssl"

Comment: In the cmd window, try `SET PATH="c:\OpsnSSL-Win64\bin";%PATH%`  to deliberately make it the first directory on the PATH. Then run openssl.  If it works, open a new CMD window, and compare the PATH values.

Comment: The `"` characters are unnecessary (there are no spaces).

Comment: Note that PowerShell does _not_ execute executables from the current directory by default, and this is by design.

Comment: If this still fails, please edit your question and copy/paste the command and output of `ECHO %Path%`.

Comment: Even if there are spaces, no `"` are needed.  However, check each item in the `PATH` variable and ensure they exist.  I have seen interesting problems (and incorrect error messages!) when one of the directories listed in `PATH` were missing at execution time.

Comment: Also, have you logged off and back on?  I've seen environment variables fail to populate just by closing and re-opening Command Prompt; the PowerShell IDE may have the same weakness.  You don't have to reboot the system, but you do have to log off when this problem manifests.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're running it in Powershell, check $env:path to be sure "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin" is in there.  Previous comments all reference the PATH variable in in cmd.exe, which your error message suggests you are not using.

If it is not, run the following command **in Powershell:**

```
$env:path = $env:path + ";C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to close the session and open a new powershell, whenever you make changes to env variable it does not work on current session.